# What are Market Share, Market Size & yield in aviation network planning?

Tags: airline-operations, flight-planning, airlines

I came across the terms Market share, size & yield in aviation network planning. I don't really know what that means, anyone can provide me with a simplified explanation or maybe a reference where I can read about it ?

Comment: These are terms not specific to aviation; they apply to business in general.

Comment: This might fit on [economics.se]. There doesn't seem to be a general [business.se], though this would probably be a perfect fit there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are terms not specific to aviation; they apply to business in general. But in an aviation network planning context they roughly translate to the following:

- market size: how big is the market: i.e. what is the total number of passengers / tonnes of cargo travelling on a (set of) route(s)? What is the total sum of money spent on the route(s).
- market share: what percentage of transport (in passenger number/tonnes of cargo, or ticket price) is provided by my company.
- market yield: how much money does the ticket sales on this route bring?

Comment: Please, if a question is not on topic here do not answer it. It gives new users the impression that a question is accepted here.

Comment: Dear @Jamiec, thank you for leaving a comment. I am not sure whether this question is not on topic here. The terms are not specific to aviation, but within the context of aviation and network planning, they do have a specific meaning. I also note that nobody voted to close, but you decided use the moderator powers to close the question on your own.  In this case, I think that is unjustified and it basically prevents any consensus building in the community on which questions are acceptable or not. I respectfully appeal to the moderators to use their powers moderately.

Comment: Its comments like that which make me want to just quit moderating this community. Take a look at [on-topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) does this fall anywhere even *close* to those? I cant see how the answer would be anything but "no". YOU should have been the one to cast the first close vote! Not answer it.

Comment: I agree the question is both general, and applicable to aviation. As such, it seems about as proportionally on topic as some of the “how do I solve this equation” questions that stand here even though they might be a better fit on mathematics.

Comment: @Jamiec I thought the question was close enough to aviation to grace it with an answer. This site has historically [many](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22669/19) [questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1857/19), [some](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22619/19) [very](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2359/19) [well](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/15545/19) [received](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16523/19), [that](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9242/19) are not strictly within the scope of our on-topic list. The list serves as a guideline...

Comment: ...not as a hard rule. I think the community should be allowed to decide in these corner cases, form an "communis opinio". I am not trying to demotivate you as a moderator, quite the contrary. But I do invite you, and all of the community, to critically look at the way we moderate this site. In my opinion, the community moderation tools are sufficient for cases like this, and do invite the community to actively participate in the moderation and discussion on the health of this site

Comment: Perhaps StackExchange should allow moderators to optionally vote as regular community members, because the power of the diamond in the current form kills all opportunity to consensus building.

Comment: Despite this terms being somewhat used also in aviation, I don't see how this information is pertinent to our SE